# ¿Cómo poner en un array el resultado del uso de informacion de dos arrays?

Tags: java

estoy aprendiendo java; estoy haciendo un programa donde convierta los cumpleaños de 5 personas en días del año (solo tomo los 365 días, no tomo en cuenta años bisiestos) pero estoy atascado: tengo los días y meses en dos arreglos, después use esas dos piezas de información que previamente puso el usuario para sacar el día del año, pero quiero almacenarlas en un `array` nuevo, ya que lo usare después para hacer un `sort` con ese `array`, este es mi código:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class birthday {
    private static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String args[]){ 
        int[]  num2 = {31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334,365};

        int value = 2;    
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] words = new String[value];
        int[] month = new int [value];
        int [] num = new int[value];
        for (int x = 0; x < value; x++) {

            System.out.println("Enter a name");
            words[x] = input.next();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));

            System.out.println("Birth month?(1 to 12) ");
            month[x] = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(month));

            System.out.println("day of the month(1 to 31) ");
            num[x] = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));       

            int month1 = month[x];
            int day = num[x];

            int sumDays;
            if (month1==1) {
                sumDays = day;
            }else {
                sumDays = num2[month1-1-1] + day;
            }

            System.out.println("the day of the birthday is " + sumDays);
            {
            }
        } 
    }   
}
```

Como ven, pregunta por nombre mes y día, después usa mes y día para sacar el día del año y al final da un `output`.

```
Enter a name
juan 
[juan, null]
Birth month?(1 to 12) 
8
[8, 0]
day of the month(1 to 31) 
14
[14, 0]
dia de cumple es  226
```

Al final quiero poner ese 226 en un `array` junto con los 4 restantes, gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya lo tenes resuelto en tu codigo.

Fijate que en cada iteracion estas llenando un vector con el valor que pedis por teclado. Con lo cual, lo unico que tenes que hacer es guardar ese valor, como haces con el resto.

```
...
int[] DiasEnElAño = new int [value];
...
if (month1==1) {
   DiasEnElAño[x] = day;
}else {
   DiasEnElAño[x] = num2[month1-1-1] + day;
}
System.out.println("the day of the birthday is " + DiasEnElAño[x]);
```

Aclararia que esta solución sirve, y  como primer paso esta bien. Pero no es recomendable, a esta altura yo pensaria en construir una matriz o un vector pero que contenga items de una clase. (Se que es un ejercicio, pero me parece que ya la complejidad es extrema en base a lo que se aprende llegado este punto).

Comment: muchas gracias, y si tienes razon, llevo mas de una semana con este codigo que ya no puedo pensar mas jajaja, y la verdad no sabria como usar las matrizes o vectores, apenas estoy empesando con arrays no eh probado otras cosas, muchas gracias.

Comment: Un vector es un array o arreglo. Diferencias de traducciones.. y una matriz seria un array de arrays..

Comment: ohh entonses me pondre a investigar sobre eso, ya que seria mucho mas facil para implemetar en mi codigo, muchas gracias, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor solución es crear un objeto persona y en el guardar esos datos, debes crear un nueva clase de java con el siguiente código:

```
public class persona {
    int day;
    int month;
    int dayOfYear;

    public persona(int day, int month, int dayOfYear) {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.dayOfYear = dayOfYear;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(int month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public int getDayOfYear() {
        return dayOfYear;
    }

    public void setDayOfYear(int dayOfYear) {
        this.dayOfYear = dayOfYear;
    } 
}
```

Al crearlo ya puedes hacer uso de este en un `List` y agregar los elementos que necesitas o que "pides" en su constructor `(int day, int month, int dayOfYear)`.

Ahora en tu clase principal creas un list y se inicializa con un arraylist()

```
List list = new ArrayList<persona>();
```

Ahora solo deberas agregar los elementos que ya recibiste a ese ArrayList

```
list.add(new persona(1,2,3));
```

Espero solucione lo que necesitas, veo que estas aprendiendo java, pero si realmente quieres dedicarte a programar para android te recomiendo aprender Kotlin, personalmente me gusta mas y es mucho mas "amigable" a la hora de escribir y leer codigo, todo el codigo anterior en kotlin se pueden resumir en tres lineas.

KOTLIN

crear objeto persona

```
data class persona (val day:Int, val month: Int, val dayOfYear: Int)
```

Acceder y agregar elementos

```
var list = ArrayList<persona>()
list.add(persona(1,2,3))
```

Un saludo y te dejo por aquí un enlace a la documentación oficial de [Kotlin](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/)

Comment: woow se ve muy interesante, lo mirare muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!